# Trim data from CHAR columns when exporting data with postgres copy command

Tags: file, postgresql, copy, export, trim

Using the COPY command (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) I get each CHAR column filled up with spaces in the resulting text file.
Is there any way to trim them during this procedure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a query instead of a table name with COPY so you can add a [`TRIM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) call to strip off the leading and trailing whitespace from your `char(n)` columns:

```
copy (select trim(some_column), ... from some_table) to stdout with csv;
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, that has nothing to do with COPY. The data type `char` is blank-padded per definition. That **is** the correct content of the column. Read the [manual about data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html).

`char` is an inheritance from an era where computer systems had a hard time with variable string length and is rarely useful nowadays. You can change this for exports like @mu describes. However, to fix this for good, use the `text` data type (or `varchar`) in your table-columns.

Comment: data types are not always a choice, but given fact. I think we will find CHAR until the UNIX doomsday ;-)